# Массив простых чисел на С

Tags: массивы, c

Как задать одномерный массив только из простых чисел в С?

Comment: Вам надо задать массив, или заполнить его простыми числами? Это учебное задание?

Comment: Как появление женщины-то сразу влияет: какое рвение у всех ответить :)

Comment: +1 прям как здесь: http://hashcode.ru/questions/13334/%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-java

Comment: Интересно, а "простые" - это математический термин тут или же синоним "целые"? =)

Answer (score 4):

Для поиска простых чисел используйте алгоритм [Решето Эратосфена](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE_%D0%AD%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0). Не смотрите на эти странные примеры.

[Вот тут](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/algorithm/91112/) есть код.

```
Arrays.fill(isPrime,true);
isPrime[1] = false;
for (int i=2; i*i < N; i++)
   if (isPrime[i])
      for (int j=i*i; j < N; j+=i)
         isPrime[j] = false;
```

Ошибся немного - там на яве. Но смысл тот же

Comment: А для того чтобы получить больше простых чисел можно использовать множества, реализованные на битовых массивах

Comment: А это вообще поиск простых чисел меньших N, а не поиск первых N простых чисел, что как мне кажется, следует из формулировки вопроса.

Comment: Именно так. Но работает гораздо быстрее. 

В любом случаи - нужен одномерный массив. У одномерного массива есть длина.

Answer (score 3):

```
int limit = 1000;
int sqr_lim;
bool is_prime[1001];
int x2, y2;
int i, j;
int n;

// Инициализация решета
sqr_lim = (int)sqrt((long double)limit);
for (i = 0; i <= limit; i++) is_prime[i] = false;
is_prime[2] = true;
is_prime[3] = true;

// Предположительно простые - это целые с нечетным числом
// представлений в данных квадратных формах.
// x2 и y2 - это квадраты i и j (оптимизация).
x2 = 0;
for (i = 1; i <= sqr_lim; i++) {
    x2 += 2 * i - 1;
    y2 = 0;
    for (j = 1; j <= sqr_lim; j++) {
        y2 += 2 * j - 1;

        n = 4 * x2 + y2;
        if ((n <= limit) && (n % 12 == 1 || n % 12 == 5))
            is_prime[n] = !is_prime[n];

        // n = 3 * x2 + y2; 
        n -= x2; // Оптимизация
        if ((n <= limit) && (n % 12 == 7))
            is_prime[n] = !is_prime[n];

        // n = 3 * x2 - y2;
        n -= 2 * y2; // Оптимизация
        if ((i > j) && (n <= limit) && (n % 12 == 11))
            is_prime[n] = !is_prime[n];
    }
}

// Отсеиваем кратные квадратам простых чисел в интервале [5, sqrt(limit)].
// (основной этап не может их отсеять)
for (i = 5; i <= sqr_lim; i++) {
    if (is_prime[i]) {
        n = i * i;
        for (j = n; j <= limit; j += n) {
            is_prime[j] = false;
        }
    }
}

// Вывод списка простых чисел в консоль.
printf("2, 3, 5"); 
for (i = 6; i <= limit; i++) {  // добавлена проверка делимости на 3 и 5. В оригинальной версии алгоритма потребности в ней нет.
    if ((is_prime[i]) && (i % 3 != 0) && (i % 5 !=  0)){
       printf(", %d", i);
    }
}

Это один из алгоритмов нахождения простых чисел "Решето Аткина"
```

Comment: Объясните, сколько памяти надо выделить под массив **is_prime** для поиска, скажем, первых 10000 простых чисел.

Answer (score 2):

Допустим, что  речь идет о первых N простых числах. Поместим в массив P[N] первые 3 {1, 2, 3}.
Вспомним, что простое число нечетное, поэтому будем перебирать только нечетные. Если очередной кандидат окажется простым, добавим его в массив и увеличим M - текущее количество простых в массиве (в начале установим M=3).

Очевидно, что испытывать надо числа, начиная с P[M-1]+2 (назовем его K). В качестве делителя будем брать уже найденные простые числа, начиная с P[2] (т.е. тройки). Если квадрат очередного делителя (P[i]*P[i]) больше K, то K простое число, занесем его в P,
если выяснили, что K составное, то увеличим его на 2.

Повторяем, пока не наберем N простых чисел.

Для достаточно больших чисел возведение в квадрат вызовет переполнение, этот момент надо отследить и учесть при определении условия прекращения цикла выбора делителей. Эффективное решение в голову, что-то не приходит, понятно, что это K, деленное на что-то (в таком случае будут лишние испытания кандидата).

Comment: @johnfelix в своем ответе привел хорошее решение проблемы переполнения при вычислении квадрата. Действительно, это решается через плавающую арифметику. 

Интересно, каково будет падение производительности ?

Answer (score 2):

```
void fill_primes(int* arr, size_t siz)
{
    int prime = 2;
    while( siz-- ) {
        *arr++ = prime;
        prime = 5 - prime;
    }
}
```

Comment: Формально Вы правы. 

(Оценил шутку).

Answer (score 1):

```
int main()
{
    int f[1000];
    int i, j;

    for (i = 2; i < 1000; i++) {
        for (j = 2; j <= (i / j); j++)
            if (!(i % j))
                break; // если число имеет множитель, оно не простое
        if (j > (i / j))
            cout << f[i] << "Простое число\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Кажется так.

Comment: А четные на простоту зачем проверять?

Comment: Товарищь AVP зайдите на вики и посмотрите http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Список_простых_чисел, что всетаки простые числа начинаются с 2. я не утверсждаю что здесь идеальный алгоритм если убрать массив то выводятся простые числа, а с массивом какойто косяк.

Comment: А кто бы сомневался, что 1, 2 и 3 простые? Просто для них и применять алгоритм не надо.

Comment: @avp не могли бы Вы назвать дату, когда число `1` было назначено простым?

Comment: Нет. 

Я всегда считал, что простым является число, которое без остатка делится только на единицу и само на себя. Для 1 это правило подходит. 

А, посмотрел Вики, ну по науке это не так (такова значит у Больших Ученых Правильная классификация терминов).

Answer (score 1):

[Вот тут интересная информация по этой теме](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/algorithm/122538/)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include "windows.h"

using namespace std;

const int N=100;  // размерность массива
int mass[N];      // объявление массива
int i,j, k;
bool flag;
int kon;

int main()
{
    k=0;

    for(i=2; k<=N; i++)
    {

            flag=false;
            for(j=2; j<i; j++)
            {
                if (i%j == 0)
                {
                    flag=true;
                }
            }
            if(flag!=true)
            {
                mass[k]=i;
                k++;
            }

    }

    for(i=0; i<N; i++)
        cout<<mass[i]<<endl;

    cin>>kon;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int massiv[100];
for( int n=2, m=0;n<=100;n++,m++)
{
    for( int i=2;i<=n; i++)
    {
        if(n%i==0 && n!=i) break;
        if(n%i==0 && n==i) 
        {
            massiv[m]=n;
            cout<<massiv[m]<<" ";
        }

    }

}
_getch();
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Да вот ещё вариант работы (с использованием [теоремы Вильсона](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0)):

```
#include <stdio.h>
const int N = 100;
int main() {
    int simplenumbers[N];
    int i, n, s;
    simplenumbers[0] = 2;
    simplenumbers[1] = 3;
    for(i=2, n=5, s=2; i<N; n+=s, s=6-s) {
       int j, fact;
       for(j=n-1, fact=1; j>1; j--) fact = (fact * j % n);
       if ((fact+1) == n ) simplenumbers[i++] = n;
    }
    for(i=0; i<N; i++) printf("%d ", simplenumbers[i]);
    putchar('\n');
}
```

Почему факториал вычисляется по модулю `n`, думаю объяснять не надо.

**UPD:** добавлено использование правила, что простое число > 3 равно 6k-1 или 6k+1