# Вывести на экран все простые числа, не превышающие заданное число, вопрос по алгоритму

Tags: c++, алгоритм, простые-числа

Да, я знаю алгоритм бредовый, но я застопорился и не могу ничего придумать, алгоритм должен быть именно переборным, перебирать делители с ограничениями для эффективности, вопрос именно по алгоритму.

```
bool flag = false;
        for (int j = 3; j < n; j+=2)
        {
          double b = sqrt(j);
          for (int a = 1; a<b; a+=2)
            {
              if (j%a == 0)
                {
                    flag = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (flag) cout << j;
        }
```

Comment: В чем состоит вопрос?

Comment: У вас внутренний цикл начинается с 1. А простые числа также делятся на 1.:)

Comment: Напишите, что не так с вашим алгоритмом.

Comment: Да, он просто выводит арифм прогрессию начиная с 3 делая +2, и я вот не могу понять как оформить алгоритм, какие условия добавить, что изменить

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/567608/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%85-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB/569413 :)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Массив простых чисел на С](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/18428/%d0%9c%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bb-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%a1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Надо не забыть 2, внести `flag` внутрь цикла, поменять его логику... 
Это если надо простой перебор. Хотите ускорить - записывайте найденные простые в массив и проверяйте делимость только на них.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int n = 100;

    cout << 2 << endl;

    for (int j = 3; j < n; j+=2)
    {
        bool flag = true;
        if (j%2 == 0) continue;
        for (int a = 3; a*a <= j; a+=2)
        {
            if (j%a == 0)
            {
                flag = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (flag) cout << j << endl;
    }

}
```

Проверка делимости только на простые:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int n = 100;
    vector<int> primes = { 2 };

    cout << 2 << endl;

    for (int j = 3; j < n; j+=2)
    {
        bool flag = true;
        for(auto i: primes)
        {
            if (j % i == 0)
            {
                flag = false;
                break;
            }
            if (i*i > j) break;
        }
        if (flag)
        {
            cout << j << endl;
            primes.push_back(j);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Странно, все равно лишние числа присутствуют, такие как 9, 25, 49

Comment: Да, заменить надо `a < b` на `a<=b`, поправил, спасибо! И вообще, убрал оттуда `sqrt` :)

Comment: да это  вам спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

У вас внутренний цикл начинается с 1

```
for (int a = 1; a<b; a+=2)
         ^^^^^
```

Поэтому для любого числа условие

```
 if (j%a == 0)
```

Всегда будет истинно. Поэтому любое число у вас будет простым.:)

Кроме того внешний цикл начинается с 3

```
for (int j = 3; j < n; j+=2)
         ^^^^^
```

А потому ваш код вообще пропускает простое число 2.

К тому же вы должны устанавливать переменную `flag`  при каждой итерации внешнего цикла.

Циклы могут выглядеть, как показано в функции `output_primes` данной демонстрационной программы

```
#include <iostream>

std::ostream & output_primes( unsigned int n, std::ostream &os = std::cout )
{
    for ( unsigned int i = 2; i <= n; i++ )
    {
        bool prime = i == 2 || i % 2;

        for ( unsigned int j = 3; prime && j * j <= i; j += 2 )  prime = i % j;

        if ( prime ) os << i << ' ';
    }

    return os;
}    

int main() 
{
    const unsigned int N = 25;

    for ( unsigned int i = 1; i <= N; i++ )
    {
        std::cout << "Prime numbers less than or equal to " << i << ": ";
        output_primes( i ) << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Ее вывод на консоль

```
Prime numbers less than or equal to 1: 
Prime numbers less than or equal to 2: 2 
Prime numbers less than or equal to 3: 2 3 
Prime numbers less than or equal to 4: 2 3 
Prime numbers less than or equal to 5: 2 3 5 
Prime numbers less than or equal to 6: 2 3 5 
Prime numbers less than or equal to 7: 2 3 5 7 
Prime numbers less than or equal to 8: 2 3 5 7 
Prime numbers less than or equal to 9: 2 3 5 7 
Prime numbers less than or equal to 10: 2 3 5 7 
Prime numbers less than or equal to 11: 2 3 5 7 11 
Prime numbers less than or equal to 12: 2 3 5 7 11 
Prime numbers less than or equal to 13: 2 3 5 7 11 13 
Prime numbers less than or equal to 14: 2 3 5 7 11 13 
Prime numbers less than or equal to 15: 2 3 5 7 11 13 
Prime numbers less than or equal to 16: 2 3 5 7 11 13 
Prime numbers less than or equal to 17: 2 3 5 7 11 13 17 
Prime numbers less than or equal to 18: 2 3 5 7 11 13 17 
Prime numbers less than or equal to 19: 2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 
Prime numbers less than or equal to 20: 2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 
Prime numbers less than or equal to 21: 2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 
Prime numbers less than or equal to 22: 2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 
Prime numbers less than or equal to 23: 2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 
Prime numbers less than or equal to 24: 2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 
Prime numbers less than or equal to 25: 2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23
```

Comment: спасибо, очень интересный метод.