# Как при выводе чисел разбить их на десятки?

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Например 1 3 5 7 9 11 17 19 надо сделать

### 1 3 5 7 9

### 11 17 19

без использования массивов, с помощью вспомогательной переменной, простой вывод чисел.

Comment: Дайте внятное ТЗ! Что дано, *в каком виде*, что точно надо сделать...

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/579338/ извиняюсь, что сразу не сказал, думал и так будет понятно, это к прошлому заданию вопрос, там вывод просто идет, а нужно его оптимизировать разбиением на десятки

Comment: @FFF3_ZE  Что это за последовательность? Как она строится и откуда берется?

Comment: @FFF3_ZE  9 не является простым числом. И надо сразу же ясно формулировать вопрос, а не заставлять других читать ваши комментарии к вашему же вопросу, чтобы понять, что вы хотите.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну, раз вам надо так делить по десяткам простые числа, то просто дополним ту программу, на которую вы указали в комментарии:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int n = 100;

    cout << 2 << endl;

    for (int last = 2, j = 3; j < n; j+=2)
    {
        bool flag = true;
        if (j%2 == 0) continue;
        for (int a = 3; a*a <= j; a+=2)
        {
            if (j%a == 0)
            {
                flag = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (flag)
        {
            if (j/10 != last/10) cout << "\n";
            cout << j << "  ";
            last = j;
        }
    }
}
```

Надеюсь, все понятно? При переходе через десяток выводим символ новой строки...

Answer (score 0):

Если исходные числа лежат в отсортированном массиве, то так

```cpp
void print(int * nums, int cnt) {
  if (cnt == 0)
    return;
  int dec = nums[0] / 10;
  for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
    int cur_dec = nums[i] / 10;
    if (curdec != dec) {
      cout << endl;
      dec = cur_dec;
    }
    cout << num[i] << ' ';
  }
}
```

Comment: К сожалению, они не лежат в массиве, но они отсортированы от меньшего к большему идут и это вроде как упрощает задачу.

Comment: @FFF3_ZE Если не в массиве, то где? Просто набор переменных `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`...?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov подозреваю, что у него цикл вычисляющий простые числа. Так что ваш подход внутри этого цикла отлично будет работать.

Comment: @Mike предположение красивое, Но там у него девятка и нет двойки :)